# Restoring Exchange 2007 to a newly installed Server

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

I am doing a DRP test on Exchange 2007 running on Windows 64BIT SP2.
I am faced with a problem - When restoring the edb files and logs I get error Connection to restore target has been lost. **I am using backup exec 12**. I have pushed the Windows remote agent from the backup server. I have full admin rights to the new exchange server. I have checked the drive partitions. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible issues here.

- Are the servers that same names
- Is the Exchange Organization name the same
- Are the databases in the same location,
- If not are you restoring to an alternative location
- Are all the Exchange Services running.
- Have you dismounted the databases?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the possible Backup Exec issues, you should not be directly backing up the EDB and LOG files unless the existing database had been dismounted on the previous server.

I would recommend reading the [Exchange 2007 DR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998890.aspx) on TechNet regarding this topic.